# What game is this screenshot of a warzone from?

Tags: game-identification

I saw an online advert for some gaming PCs, and one of them had a screenshot from most probably some kind of FPS game:

[image]
(Sorry for the low resolution, as the ad was like that)

I'm not a big fan of shooter games so I don't know which game it could be from. I'd probably try it out, if only I knew the game. **What game is this screenshot from?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's from Bf1 (Battlefield 1) on the map [Sinai Desert](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Sinai_Desert)

Comment: That was fast! Is Battlefield a new game?

Comment: It was launched about a month ago and the public beta a month and a half before

Comment: It seems I missed a new hyped-up game again :)

Comment: Yeah, you absolutely did :D *really good game by the way*

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek battlefield 1 is new but it's not the first battlefield game. The title is a misnomer, as it follows Battlefield 4 and Battlefield Hardline. The reason it's called Battlefield 1 is that it takes place during World War 1. Thought I'd clarify.

Answer (score 6):

That would be [Battlefield 1](https://www.battlefield.com/games/battlefield-1/maps) by Dice